# Filtering a remote JSON file before feeding it to a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a remote JSON file stored on s3 which has the following format:

```
[
  {"animal_type":"dog", "name":"spike", "age":"7"},
  {"animal_type":"cat", "name":"tom", "age":"1"}
  // and so on
]
```

The data has no particular order.

I am using Handsontable plugin to display the data as a spreadsheet. My code now looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://s3.aws.com/url.json',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data) {
    new Handsontable($('#data-grid')[0], {
      data: data,
      rowHeaders: true,
      colHeaders: true
    });
  }
```

I would like to do

- Get only certain JSON fields

and

- Display them in a certain order

Basically, instead of the data above I would like to have it look like this:

```
[
  {"pet_name":"spike", "animal":"dog"},
  {"pet_name":"tom", "animal":"cat"}
  // and so on
]
```

I understand that I need to iterate through my `data` object and do something like:

```
var new_data = $.each(data, function(i, item){
  // do stuff
});
```

but I'm a bit lost on how to re-instantiate a JSON object in this case.

Comment: If possible this would be much more worthwhile if you could do it on the server. Filtering on the client still means you have to download the *entire* dataset first, then perform whatever logic on it, which is much slower. Also note that ordering the properties of an object is moot, they are not guaranteed to stay in that order.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan by the looks of it, its on S3 so filtering server side would not be possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan slower by what? A millisecond or two. You're making an assumption that post-processing JSON somehow will be noticeable by the user.

Comment: True, I am making an assumption. However if the OP is using S3 to store the file it's probably not going to be a simple shopping list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$.map` function like this:

```
var new_data = $.map(data, function(i, item) {
    return {"pet_name":item['name'], "animal":item['animal_type'] };
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

**Updated:**

You can make the remapping of values configurable like this:

```
var data = [
    {"animal_type":"dog", "name":"spike", "age":"7"},
    {"animal_type":"cat", "name":"tom", "age":"1"}
    // and so on
];

var columns = {
    "name": "pet_name",
    "animal_type": "animal"
};

var new_data = $.map(data, function(item, i) {
    var value = {};
    $.each(item, function(propName, obj) {
        value[columns[propName]] = obj;
    });
    return value;
});

console.log(new_data);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/5p0c55e5/

If you're going to be doing a lot of work like this in JavaScript. There are libraries that offer a broader range of functionality than jQuery's collection functions.

https://lodash.com/

Comment: I think this is what I need, thank you for answering. Can you maybe slightly extend the code, given I might have a pre-set array of required columns before I actually start iterating? For example `required_columns = ['name', 'animal_type']`

Comment: However I could not make your updated code work yet, as it gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 1` console error

Comment: @TheWhizofOz sorry, the code had a few mistakes. Updated with a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Interesting, if I add additional "text": "random text" to each data value object, it shows up in the console as a new undefined key/value: https://jsfiddle.net/5p0c55e5/1/ - any idea why that is?

Comment: "text" doesn't exist in the `columns` mapping object. So the target property name becomes the string value of `undefined`.

Comment: but that does not happen to the "age" column? Can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: it is happening to the age column, except that the other column is overwriting "undefined". The code just needs to be updated to skip property names missing from columns.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the `success` response after the ajax call, You can simple use `Array.reduce` to change the `json` structure, and pass on the data to the next function.

One thing you need to take care of is to convert the `JSON` data into `javascript array/object` by using `JSON.parse(data)` first.

```js
let data = [
  {"animal_type":"dog", "name":"spike", "age":"7"},
  {"animal_type":"cat", "name":"tom", "age":"1"}
];

data = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.pet_name = curr.name;
  obj.animal = curr.animal_type;
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I would not classify a reduce function as simple for someone who is new to javascript.

Comment: That's a personal opinion @cgTag. SO is to help solve the problems and new or not , person asking the question should also put in an effort to update his knowledge I guess.

Comment: Very true! I +1 your answer as another possible approach. I shouldn't have criticized. Sorry.